# Reading names of directories in /data/data/

Tags: android, root, android-file

I'm trying get my app to get the name of every app on the device. The best way I can think of doing this is reading the name of every directory in /data/data/ into a list. I have the following code which works on other directories but not /data/data/.

```
public void generateDirList() {
        File rootDir = new File(currentLocation);
        String[] directories = rootDir.list();
        subDirs = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(String dir : directories)
        {
            if (new File(currentLocation + File.separator + dir).isDirectory())
            {
                Log.i(TAG, dir);
                subDirs.add(dir);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem seems to be that /data isn't being recognized as a directory so `rootDir.list()` returns null. My device is rooted and I have the following in my manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />`

What else do I have to do to get this to work ?

Comment: Even if your device is rooted your app must have been granted root access by an app called Superuser. How you can obtain them... please find out and tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying get my app to get the name of every app on the device

Use `PackageManager` and [methods like `getInstalledApplications()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications%28int%29).

> The problem seems to be that /data isn't being recognized as a directory so rootDir.list() returns null.

No, the problem is that you do not have read access to `/data`.

> I have the following in my manifest

There is [no such permission defined in Android](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml).

> What else do I have to do to get this to work ?

<strike>I presume that you can use **`su`** to run **`ls -R`** or something like that.</strike> I suggest that you use `PackageManager`.

Comment: su command does not work even on rooted devices - except when called via `adb shell`

Comment: @Mr.Radar: Sorry, I don't write apps that run on rooted devices, so I took an educated guess. I have edited my answer. Thanks!